# 4 dimensions vector without repetition

Tags: matlab, loops

I have the following code in Matlab:

```
clear all;

B = 3;
U = 2;

i = 1;

for j=1:B
    for u=1:U
        for u0=u:U
            for j0=j:B
                A(i,:)=[u j u0 j0];
                i = i + 1;
            end
        end
    end
end
```

What I want to write is the combination of all (u,j) and (u0,j0) without repetitions. By repetitions I mean that for example `(1,2),(2,3)` is the same as `(2,3),(1,2)` or in the code `[1 2 2 3]` equals `[2 3 1 2]`. This should give me 21 combinations. But I am only having 18.

How can I improve the code?

Comment: Is `(1,2),(2,3)` the same as `(1,2),(3,2)`?

Comment: No. `(1,2),(2,3)` is the same as `(2,3),(1,2)`. This is because indexes are used to calculate a quantity where the order doesn't matter outside backets, but inside it must kept.

Comment: Do you know what the three cases you are missing are? I can't work it out by looking at the results.

Comment: `(2,1),(1,2)` and `(2,1),(1,3)` and `(2,2),(1,3)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how big the problem you wish to solve is, here is one possible method.

```
[bm,um]=meshgrid(1:B,1:U); % Get all the combinations of 1:B and 1:U
M=[um(:) bm(:)]; % These are the distinct pairs of digits to combine
P=[(1:U*B).'*[1 1];nchoosek(1:U*B,2)]; % This gives row indices for all the pairs we want
A=[M(P(:,1),:) M(P(:,2),:)] % This Uses those row indices to give the desired matrix
```

Let me know if anything doesn't make sense.

Comment: +1 Good approach. I was thinking `ndgrid`, sorting and removing duplicates, but `nchoosek` already does that. Maybe replace that `6` by `U*B`?

Comment: This indeed works. Now I wanted to write this in an algorithmic form. With `for`s and `while`s it is easy. But with the code above I cannot figure it out.